# Is there a function to reverse an array, but only specific indexes?

Tags: python, arrays, reverse

I need help to find a way to reverse a list. The only condition is to reverse specific index ranges. For example if my arr is [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], and you must reverse everything from index 2 to 5, then the end arr would be [0,1,5,4,3,2,6,7]? I code in Python3. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Ideally, you should provide some code, to help the community help you.

Answer (score 2):

To reverse indexes `a` to `b`, you can use the slice (`[:]`) operator and the function [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed):

```py
l[a:b + 1] = reversed(l[a:b + 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = list(range(8))
a[0:2] + list(reversed(a[2:5])) + a[5:]
```

This should reverse only the specific portion that you want and welcome to Stackoverflow!